# How do I prove $[0,3)$ is an open set in $([0,\infty),d)$ standard metric?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

**Question :** How do I prove $[0,3)$ is an open set in $([0,\infty),d)$ standard metric?

**Background and Approach :** This is my first analysis class and I don't know if I'm on the right path. I'm thinking about proving if every point in the interval has a neighborhood contained in it, but the $[0,\infty)$ confuses me. I know that a set $X$ is open if given any $x \in X\; \exists \;r\in\mathbb{R^+}$ such that $B(x,r) \in X$.

Comment: $[0,3)$ is the open ball of radius $3$ around $0$ in this space.

Comment: Hi Natalia. Do you know the definition of an open set in a metric space? Could you write out what it would mean for this set to be open in this space? Also, do you happen to have come across any theorems that you're allowed to use about open sets?

Comment: Yes, I do. A set X is open if given any x in X there exists a real number r>0 s.t  B(x,r) belongs to X. And about the theorems I'm allowed to use, I've only seen the intX=X

Comment: OK, that's good! So suppose $x$ is an arbitrary real number with $0 \le x < 3$. What $r$ could we choose so that whenever $|y - x| < r$, we have $y < 3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the last comment, you need to find an $r$ such that $B(x,r)\subset [0,3)$, whenever $x\in [0,3).$

**Hint:** Instead of $x$, you can write $0\le x=3-\epsilon<3,$ where $0<\epsilon\le 3.$ Namely, you can express every element in $[0,3)$ as $3-\epsilon$, for some $\epsilon\in(0,3].$

> Set $$r=\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\frac{3-x}{2},$$ for any $x\in[0,3)$.
> (Anything less than $\epsilon$ should work.)

Comment: Yes, this is very clear, but what about the metric space, the $ [0, \infty) $ ? Could you please look at the previous answer and tell me if the set $ X = (0,3) $ is right? But thanks, this really does it.

Comment: If you mean your question under the previous answer, you are right. $(0,3)\cap [0,\infty)=(0,3)$ indeed. The reason why this $r$ works is the metric space $\left([0,\infty),d\right).$ Notice that if you had $(-\infty,\infty)$ instead of $[0,\infty),$ $[0,3)$ wouldn't be open since any ball centered at $0$ would not be contained in $[0,3).$

Comment: Yes, actually I had to do it for both cases, with the $ \mathbb{R} $ case was an easy one, my issue was proving this one, but thank youu!

Answer (score 1):

To prove $U = [0, 3)$ is an open set in $V = [0, \infty)$ with standard metric you need to find an set $X$ such that

$U = X \cap V $ and $X$ is open in the $\mathbb{R}$ w.r.t standard metric.

Taking $X = (-1, 3)$ would work in this case.

Comment: Thank you! I got this, really appreciate it!

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing this wrong, but that intersection would not be $ (0,3) $ ? But we need $ U = [0, 3) $ no?

Comment: You're right, the set from $X = (-1, 3)$ should work. Apologies for the mistake.